# WebStorm: Converting direct-return arrow function into multi-line arrow function

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is an automatic conversion of the following kind possible?

```
const cuteLittleFunction = input=>value;
```

to:

```
const cuteLittleFunction = input=> {
   return value;
};
```

I find myself doing this a lot, and it gets pretty annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put cursor on `input`, hit `Alt+Enter`, choose **Add braces to arrow function statement**:

[image]

Code will be changed to

```
const cuteLittleFunction = input => {
    return value;
};
```